# How to use generics to combine duplicate methods with a parameter that has different Java Collections containing the same class type?

Tags: java, generics, methods, collections

The below two methods have the exact same code underneath. Is there way to decrease code duplication by using Java Generics here to combine them into a single method?

```
public static List<String> convert(List<Magic> magicStrings);
```

Note, `RealmList<E>` extends `List<E>`.

```
public static List<String> convert(RealmList<Magic> magicStrings);
```

Comment: Are RealmList and List somehow related? Eg. does RealmList implement/ extend List?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the two methods have the exact same code, then there is no point in keeping the method with the more specific parameter.

Remove the `convert` method that takes a `RealmList`.  Any code that wants to call `convert`, with a `RealmList` or any other kind of `List`, can use the `convert` method that takes a `List`.

Answer (score 2):

If `RealmList<E>` extends `List<E>`, just delete `convert(RealmList<Magic> magicStrings);`

Then `convert(someRealmList)` will actually use the `convert(List<Magic> magicStrings)` implementation.